# How can I use hypertools plot the dynamic graphic about mouse trajectory according to time?

Tags: python, visualization

I find a powerful tool in kaggle which is [hypertools](http://blog.kaggle.com/2017/04/10/exploring-the-structure-of-high-dimensional-data-with-hypertools-in-kaggle-kernels/). I find that it can plot dynamic graph. Just a single line code.

```
hyp.plot(temps, normalize='across', animate=True, chemtrails=True)
```

[image]

I think this is pretty cool. However, I do not know how use this tools to plot for my data. My data is a list of tuple (x, y, t) like this:

```
array([[  353.,  2607.,   349.],
       [  367.,  2607.,   376.],
       [  388.,  2620.,   418.],
       [  416.,  2620.,   442.],
       [  500.,  2620.,   493.],
       [  584.,  2620.,   547.],
       [  675.,  2620.,   592.],
       [  724.,  2620.,   643.],
       [  780.,  2620.,   694.],
       [  822.,  2620.,   742.],
       [  850.,  2633.,   793.],
       [  885.,  2633.,   844.],
       [  934.,  2633.,   895.],
       [  983.,  2633.,   946.],
       [ 1060.,  2633.,  1006.],
       [ 1144.,  2633.,  1063.],
       [ 1235.,  2633.,  1093.],
       [ 1284.,  2633.,  1144.],
       [ 1312.,  2633.,  1210.],
       [ 1326.,  2633.,  1243.],
       [ 1333.,  2633.,  1354.],
       [ 1354.,  2633.,  1408.],
       [ 1375.,  2646.,  1450.],
       [ 1452.,  2659.,  1492.],
       [ 1473.,  2672.,  1543.],
       [ 1480.,  2672.,  1954.]])
```

How can I use this powerful tool to plot mouse trajectory?

Comment: Study the [example notebooks](https://github.com/ContextLab/hypertools-paper-notebooks) (including [the one you quoted](https://github.com/ContextLab/hypertools-paper-notebooks/blob/master/temperatures.ipynb)).

Comment: Thanks, I have read this notebook. However, I don't know how to pass the parameter. Such that I can plot a line made up of many points (x,y). At the same time, it moves according to the time t.